# href mailto and iOS safari

Tags: html, ios, google-chrome, safari, mailto

Upon trying a regular  mailto element on my html, I noticed that one needs to keep pressing the link in iPhone Safari to be prompted to send a message. As suggested in a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42839716/ios-tel-and-mailto-links-only-work-with-target-blank), I tried adding target="_blank", as follows: `<a href="mailto:foo@bar.com" target="_blank">Hi</a>`

This solves the issue on iPhone (one click opens an email draft). However, this leaves a blank page open in Chrome when using desktop. It there a way to keep the single-click-draft functionality for Iphone without otherwise opening a blank page from desktop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of simply using an anchor element have you tried using the `<form action="">` element to handle the `mailto` URL? While this is traditionally used to organize/collect data to send server-side, I've found it's useful to flatten usage for compatibility sake.

```html
    <form action="mailto:foo@bar.com" method="get">
      <button style="background:none; border:none;" type="submit">Hi</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: Cool option! Is this at all compatible with a pre-filled subject line, etc? (e.g. mailto:no-one@snai1mai1.com?subject=free)

Comment: Absolutely is. Anything after "mailto" is  treated as a URL by the browser/mail client. So you can (and I have) passed in whole e-mail formatting. Example to test in your browser bar: action="mailto:myaddress@email.com?cc=another@address.com&subject=Cool&body=yo!"