# Substitute for mailto that works on safari

Tags: html, forms, email, mailto

I recently created a platform called supplyneighbor.com where neighbors in the nearby area can offer surplus supplies or request for supplies that they are in need of to other people in the area. When someone is able to accept an offer or request, they press an accept button that would send an email notification to the person that made the request notifying them that someone accepted their request. I used a "mailto" action on the anchor tag to send the email; however, the "mailto" button doesn't work for people using safari and also sometimes doesn't work when the email on a computer is set to "chrome." Is there any other way to send an email that is better than "mailto" but also makes sure that the communication stays between only the neighbors that are requesting and accepting? Thank you in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51296641/href-mailto-and-ios-safari

Comment: Sorry about the confusion, I was referring to safari on the mac and not the iphone, the iphone works for me.